# ES6 javascript syntax error hash of array map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is a silly question, but I just stuck here.

Premise

```
let groups = [
  {id: 1, name: '123'},
  {id: 2, name: '456'}
]
```

And I want to output this

```
[
  {value: 1, label: '123'},
  {value: 2, label: '456'}
]
```

I don't understand why it causes an error.

```
groupOptions = groups.map(item =>
  {value: item.id, label: item.name}
)
```

Comment: You forgot to add parenthesis inside map after arrow.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the returned object into `()`. Withour `()` curly braces will be considered to be the arrow function’s body and inside the body your expressions are invalid.

```js
let groups = [
  {id: 1, name: '123'},
  {id: 2, name: '456'}
]

var groupOptions = groups.map(item =>
  ({value: item.id, label: item.name})
);

console.log(groupOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let groups = [
  {id: 1, name: '123'},
  {id: 2, name: '456'}
]
var output = groupOptions = groups.map(item =>
  {return {value: item.id, label: item.name}}
)

console.log(output);
```

You need to wrap your map callback code in {}:

```
let groups = [
  {id: 1, name: '123'},
  {id: 2, name: '456'}
]
groupOptions = groups.map(item =>
  {return {value: item.id, label: item.name}}
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the `return` is not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more clean if you destructure the `item` argument of your `map` callback:

```
let groups = [
  {id: 1, name: '123'},
  {id: 2, name: '456'}
]
var output = groupOptions = groups.map(({id,name}) => 
    ({value:id, label:name})
);

// or you can do the mapping right in the arguments:

var output = groupOptions = ggroups.map(({id:value,name:label}) =>
    ({value, label})
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want it to be simpler.